# Why doesn't scipy.sparse.csc_matrix preserve the indexing order of my np.array?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-indexing

I am writing code to remove multiple columns from several large, parallel scipy `sparse.csc` matrices (meaning all matrices have the same dim, and all nnz elements are in the same places) simultaneously and efficiently. I am doing this by indexing to only the columns I want to keep for one matrix and then reusing the indices and indptr lists for the others. However, when I index the csc matrix by a list, it reorders the data list, so I cannot reuse the indices. Is there a way to force scipy to keep the data list in the original order? Why is it reordering only when indexing by a list?

```py
import scipy.sparse
import numpy as np
mat = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(np.array([[1,0,0,0,2,5], 
                                        [1,0,1,0,0,0], 
                                        [0,0,0,4,0,1],
                                        [0,3,0,1,0,4]]))
print mat[:,3].data
```

returns array([4, 1])

```py
print mat[:,[3]].data
```

returns array([1, 4])

Comment: `csc` indexing with a list uses matrix multiplication.  It constructs an extractor matrix based on the index, and then does the `dot` multiply.  So it's a brand new sparse matrix; not just a subset of the `csc` data and index attributes.

Comment: `csc` matrices have a method to ensure the `indicies` values are ordered (within a column).  Applying that might help to ensure the arrays are sorted in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [43]: mat = sparse.csc_matrix(np.array([[1,0,0,0,2,5],[1,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,4,
    ...: 0,1],[0,3,0,1,0,4]])) 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                        
In [44]: mat                                                                    
Out[44]: 
<4x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
In [45]: mat.data                                                               
Out[45]: array([1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 5, 1, 4], dtype=int64)
In [46]: mat.indices                                                            
Out[46]: array([0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
In [47]: mat.indptr                                                             
Out[47]: array([ 0,  2,  3,  4,  6,  7, 10], dtype=int32)
```

scalar selection:

```
In [48]: m1 = mat[:,3]                                                          
In [49]: m1                                                                     
Out[49]: 
<4x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
In [50]: m1.data                                                                
Out[50]: array([4, 1])
In [51]: m1.indices                                                             
Out[51]: array([2, 3], dtype=int32)
In [52]: m1.indptr                                                              
Out[52]: array([0, 2], dtype=int32)
```

list indexing:

```
In [53]: m2 = mat[:,[3]]                                                        
In [54]: m2.data                                                                
Out[54]: array([1, 4], dtype=int64)
In [55]: m2.indices                                                             
Out[55]: array([3, 2], dtype=int32)
In [56]: m2.indptr                                                              
Out[56]: array([0, 2], dtype=int32)
```

sorting:

```
In [57]: m2.sort_indices()                                                      
In [58]: m2.data                                                                
Out[58]: array([4, 1], dtype=int64)
In [59]: m2.indices                                                             
Out[59]: array([2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

> csc indexing with a list uses matrix multiplication. It constructs an extractor matrix based on the index, and then does the dot multiply. So it's a brand new sparse matrix; not just a subset of the csc data and index attributes.
>
> csc matrices have a method to ensure the indicies values are ordered (within a column). Applying that might help to ensure the arrays are sorted in the same way.

Comment: This is just an IPython session transcript, not an answer.

Comment: @user2357112, sorry, I forgot to copy-n-paste my comments to my answer :(